# Is there a way to convert an MVC 3 Model to Knockout View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

Perhaps I am missing something from the Knockout.js tutorial, but I find it a clear violation of the DRY principle to re-declare a model in knockout that has already been declared in MVC. Is there a way I can use the same model without re-declaring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize it as Json (using Json.NET).  But you have to unwrap circular dependencies.

What we tend to do is manually serialize the objects and type information so that we only send to the browser the information necessary.   But the browser can send back a model ( with the partial information) and the model binder will convert back to the C# model.

Comment: This is precisely what I've been doing. it works well as you only end up writing behaviors in your JavaScript, and not a whole model.

Comment: Unless your model is really big, I think the manual serialization may add unnecessary code.